# backbone.js View determine which attribute of model is change

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-model

How can I know which attribute of the view model is changed in the render function? (In the render function, "e" is the model, but I need only the attribute which is changed.) I need to know this to know which template to use. Or is there another method to do this?

```
window.Person = Backbone.Model.extend({});

window.Njerzit = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Person,
    url: '/Home/Njerzit'
});

window.PersonView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'span',

    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.model.bind('change', this.render);
    },

    render: function (e) {
        //if model name is changed, I need to render another template
        this.template = _.template($('#PersonTemplate').html());
        var renderContent = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
        $(this.el).html(renderContent);
        return this;
    }
});
```

Comment: both answers below offer solutions, but the easiest one is using a more specific event like the change:attrName  in your case change:Name ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe the `changedAttributes` function is what you're looking for

> **changedAttributesmodel.changedAttributes([attributes])**
>   Retrieve a hash of only the model's attributes that have changed. Optionally,
>   an external attributes hash can be passed in, returning the attributes
>   in that hash which differ from the model. This can be used to figure
>   out which portions of a view should be updated, or what calls need to
>   be made to sync the changes to the server.

or to check if a specific attribute has changed use the `hasChanged` function

> **hasChangedmodel.hasChanged([attribute])**
>   Has the model changed since the last "change" event? If an attribute is passed, returns true
>   if that specific attribute has changed.

```
var nameChanged = this.model.hasChanged("name");
```

- From [Backbone Docs](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-changedAttributes)

Answer (score 12):

You can bind to `change:name` if you only want to notify if the name has changed: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-set